# How can I build WSP files (SharePoint 2013 Web Part packages) with TeamCity

Tags: sharepoint, msbuild, teamcity, wsp

I am automating the build of a Sharepoint 2013 Web Part using TeamCity 9.1.4

The build runs fine and creates the DLL output.

*How can I make TeamCity create WSP files (same output as clicking Deploy on Web Part project in Visual Studio)?*

I am particularly interested in an experience of someone who set it up succesfully, I am aware of lots of articles mentioning using /t:Package argument for msbuild, and older posts mentioning WSPBuilder. I just cannot make it work in my TeamCity build.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out I have to add as command line parameter in the TeamCity build step '/p:IsPackaging=true'. Now adding the necessary DLLs and fixing further issues ...

Comment: And now I am stuck with the following error: [ValidatePackage] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(450, 5): Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. I guess I'll have to ask my own build server and install full Visual Studio 2015 with Office Developer Tools   :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works.

The flag to use for MSBuild.exe is **/p:IsPackaging=true**, you can enter it in the command line parameters of your TeamCity build step.

I added the following DLLs in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ProjectExtensions.CodeGenerators.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Remote.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Wsp.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Commands.Implementation.v5.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Features.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Packages.dll
- Microsoft.Office.Sharepoint.Tools.dll

I found which DLL was missing by using the FusionLogs approach described by Scott Hanselman in [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)